# How to fix "submatrix incorrectly defined" in Scilab?

Tags: optimization, ode, least-squares, scilab

I am trying to find three parameters (a, b, c) to fit my experimental data using ODE solver and optimization by least squares using Scilab in-built functions. 
However, I keep having the message "submatrix incorrectly defined" at line "y_exp(:,1) = [0.135 ..."

When I try another series of data (t, yexp) such as the one used in the original template I get no error messages. The template I use was found here: https://wiki.scilab.org/Non%20linear%20optimization%20for%20parameter%20fitting%20example

```
function dy = myModel ( t , y , a , b, c ) 
// The right-hand side of the Ordinary Differential Equation.
dy(1) = -a*y(1) - b*y(1)*y(2) 
dy(2) = a*y(1) - b*y(1)*y(2) - c*y(2)
endfunction 

function f = myDifferences ( k ) 
// Returns the difference between the simulated differential 
// equation and the experimental data.
global MYDATA
t = MYDATA.t
y_exp = MYDATA.y_exp
a = k(1) 
b = k(2) 
c = k(3)
y0 = y_exp(1,:)
t0 = 0
y_calc=ode(y0',t0,t,list(myModel,a,b,c)) 
diffmat = y_calc' - y_exp
// Make a column vector
f = diffmat(:)
MYDATA.funeval = MYDATA.funeval+ 1
endfunction 

// Experimental data 

t = [0,20,30,45,75,105,135,180,240]'; 
y_exp(:,1) = 
[0.135,0.0924,0.067,0.0527,0.0363,0.02445,0.01668,0.012,0.009]'; 
y_exp(:,2) = 
[0,0.00918,0.0132,0.01835,0.0261,0.03215,0.0366,0.0393,0.0401]'; 

// Store data for future use
global MYDATA;
MYDATA.t = t;
MYDATA.y_exp = y_exp;
MYDATA.funeval = 0;

function val = L_Squares ( k ) 
// Computes the sum of squares of the differences.
f = myDifferences ( k ) 
val = sum(f.^2)
endfunction 

// Initial guess
a = 0; 
b = 0; 
c = 0;
x0 = [a;b;c];  

[fopt ,xopt]=leastsq(myDifferences, x0)
```

Does anyone know how to approach this problem?

Comment: You are accessing a non-existing array. Why not define `y_exp = [ [...,...,...],  [...,...,...] ]'`?

Comment: Could you be more clear?

Comment: With `y_exp(:,1)` you are addressing a view of the object `y_exp`. But at that point the object does not exist. With one-dimensional arrays you get automatic extension or construction, but with higher-dimensional matrices that is more difficult. You probably can assign the list to  `y_exp(1)` etc. but then have to remember the transposed state of `y_exp` in the other places it is used.

Answer (score 1):

Just rewrite lines 28,29 as

```
y_exp = [0.135,0.0924,0.067,0.0527,0.0363,0.02445,0.01668,0.012,0.009 
         0,0.00918,0.0132,0.01835,0.0261,0.03215,0.0366,0.0393,0.0401]';
```

or insert a `clear` at line 1 (you may have defined `y_exp` before with a different size).